# Transposing a column in a pandas dataframe while keeping other column intact with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, transpose

My data frame is as follows

```
selection_id  last_traded_price
430494        1.46
430494        1.48
430494        1.56
430494        1.57
430495        2.45
430495        2.67
430495        2.72
430495        2.87
```

I have lots of rows that contain selection id's and I need to keep selection_id column the same but transpose the data in last traded price to look like this.

```
selection_id  last_traded_price
430494        1.46              1.48          1.56      1.57    e.t.c 
430495        2.45              2.67          2.72      2.87    e.t.c
```

I've tried a to use a pivot

```
   (df.pivot(index='selection_id', columns=last_traded_price', values='last_traded_price')
```

Pivot isn't working due to duplicate rows in selection_id.
is it possible to transpose the data first and drop the duplicates after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`groupby` + `apply`

```
v = df.groupby('selection_id').last_traded_price.apply(list)
pd.DataFrame(v.tolist(), index=v.index)

                 0     1     2     3
selection_id                        
430494        1.46  1.48  1.56  1.57
430495        2.45  2.67  2.72  2.87
```

---

**Option 2**
You *can* do this with `pivot`, as long as you have another column of counts to pass for the pivoting (it needs to be pivoted along *something*, that's why).

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby('selection_id').cumcount()
df.pivot('selection_id', 'Count', 'last_traded_price')

Count            0     1     2     3
selection_id                        
430494        1.46  1.48  1.56  1.57
430495        2.45  2.67  2.72  2.87
```

Comment: Now it is perfectly OK, only you can change `pd.Series.tolist` to `list` for better answer ;)

Comment: @jezrael Thank you so much, that's exactly what I could benefit from...

Comment: @jezrael thank dude your answer solved my issue. I would rate best answer but I don't have enough reputation to do that. I will when I do!

Comment: @tomoc4 you can still accept his answer. You can also upvote both answers, because I think they're good.

Comment: @coldspeed I tried running both solutions and for some reason my output isn't what I expected. Maybe I wasn't specific enough in the original question. for some reason selection_id is printing along columns also. I need to transpose last_traded_price first then after that's done drop the rows that contain duplicate selection_id's. I'd like to mention also I'm trying this on 4 million rows!

Comment: @tomoc4 my answer gives the same thing that the accepted answer does. Are you saying my answer isn't working? Specifically, what part is wrong? If you can explain in more detail, I'll see if I can give you an alternative.

Comment: @coldspeed both answers actually print the same rows and columns sizes so are identical.  Each row that contains selection_id in the corresponding column contains a price movement (last_traded_price). What I'm trying to capture is the range of price movements related to the selection_id. I've just pasted a sample of the column data here if you want to try. https://pastebin.com/8K6ktrdK 

I'm not sure why the selection_id's eventually print along the columns it might be due to using selection_id as an index

Comment: Would it be possible to create a list of all last_traded_price rows relating to the selection_id instead?

Comment: @tomoc4 if I understood, it seems you can just call result.reset_index() to remove it from the index.

Comment: @coldspeed I just tried this on the sample paste I made and it works fine. It must be an index issue. How do I call result.reset_index() ?

Comment: @tomoc4 If you're using my code, change the second line in option 1 to `pd.DataFrame(v.tolist(), index=v.index).reset_index()`

Comment: @coldspeed that's not working. It's corrupting the data for some reason I get this format 

1565,"[3.0499999999999998, 3.0499999999999998, 3.0499999999999998, 3.0499999999999998, 3.0499999999999998, 3.0499999999999998, 3.5499999999999998, 3.5, 3.6000000000000001, 3.6000000000000001, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5499999999999998, 3.5499999999999998, 3.5499999999999998, 3.5499999999999998, 3.5499999999999998, 3

Comment: @tomoc4 That isn't corrupt data, that's just floating point inaccuracies. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @coldspeed I just figured that out. Thanks man you helped me a lot and I learnt new things about pandas. because of you. Thanks again!

Comment: @tomoc4 No worries, anytime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for Counter for new columns names created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or [`pandas.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html):

```
g = df.groupby('selection_id').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['selection_id',g])['last_traded_price'].unstack()
print (df)
                 0     1     2     3
selection_id                        
430494        1.46  1.48  1.56  1.57
430495        2.45  2.67  2.72  2.87
```

Similar solution with `pivot`:

```
df = pd.pivot(index=df['selection_id'], 
              columns=df.groupby('selection_id').cumcount(), 
              values=df['last_traded_price'])
print (df)
                 0     1     2     3
selection_id                        
430494        1.46  1.48  1.56  1.57
430495        2.45  2.67  2.72  2.87
```